# GRE Practice book problem 42: Open and Closed subspaces of Metric Space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

The [GRE Practice book](https://www.ets.org/s/gre/pdf/practice_book_math.pdf) includes this problem (#42).

> Let $\mathbb{Z}^+$ be the set of positive integers, and $d$ be a metric defined on $\mathbb{Z}^+$ by:
>   $d(m, n) = \begin{cases} 
>       0 & m=n \\
>       1 & m \neq n.
>    \end{cases}$
>
> Which of the following statements are true about this metric space?
>
> I. If $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, then ${n}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{Z}^+$.
>
> II. Every subset of $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is closed.
>
> III. Every real-valued function on $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is continuous.
>
> (A) None
>
> (B) I only
>
> (C) III only
>
> (D) I and II only
>
> (E) I, II, and II

### My thoughts so far

Choice I) Is it talking about the set of all $n$ (eg. $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$) or is it talking about any individual singleton (eg. $\{2\}$ or $\{9\}$)? I assumed the latter and decided this was false because no elements in the set $\mathbb{Z}^+$ are interior points.

Choice II) True for the same reasoning as above.

Choice III) True

### The “correct” answer

According to the practice test, the answer is E, all three. I wasn't surprised that I got the answer wrong because I'm struggling with open vs closed sets when it isn't the easy cases in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I really don't see how both choices I and II can be True. They sound obviously mutually exclusive to me.

Please help me figure out what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3):

If $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, then $\{n\}=B_1(n)$. Therefore, $\{n\}$ is an open set.

If $M\subset\mathbb{Z}^+$, then $M=\bigcup_{n\in M}\{n\}$. Since this expresses $M$ as an union of open sets, $M$ is open. But then $M$ is closed too, because, $\mathbb{Z}^+\setminus M$ is open.

And never forget: sets are not doors. A set may well be simultaneously open and closed and it can also be neither open nor closed.

Comment: doors can be ajar!